# Using new operator to statically allocate an object

Tags: c++, heap-memory, new-operator, delete-operator, stack-memory

Of course the next should not be done although it is valid for the compiler. But what is happening when you do?

```
CClass clss = *new CClass();
```

On the contrary to the above, the next does compile but gives an assertion error.

```
delete &clss;
```

Does this have something to do with allocating memory on either the stack or the heap?

Comment: the `clss` instance becomes a copy of a value-initialized, dynamically allocated `CClass` instance, and has an automatic storage which cannot* be deallocated with a `delete` (*unless this class provides a class-specific `delete` operator)

Comment: @PiotrS. my logic tells me such a class-specific `delete` operator should be  restrained to clean up members, is that true?

Comment: its destructor that is responsible for proper members cleanup, actually with a class specific delete called on automatic storage instance it will get called twice

Comment: Mixing storage types in obscure ways is s recipe for desaster, even when it _seems_ to work fine for the moment. Don't do that, at best you'll create memory leaks, at worst untraceable errors from accessing destroyed objects. If you allocate something dynamically, don't lie about what you've done.

Comment: @Damon. I'll promise not to lie. +1

Comment: The code which does behave like you expected would be `CClass& clss = *new CClass(); delete &clss;`. Note the first `&`, this makes `clss` a reference instead of a copy. (Still very bad style)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line of code is correct, you initialize a statically allocated `CClass` instance with an another instance dynamically allocated.

The second is obviously wrong as you try to delete an object that has not been dynamically allocated .

The first line produces a memory leak because you dynamically allocate a bunch of memory but never retain its address, so it can never be deallocated (deleted).

Comment: So when you do `CClass* clssPtr = new CClass(); CClass class = *clssPtr; delete classPtr;` would be valid for the delete operator?

Comment: Note: formally speaking, not calling `delete` on a pointer obtained by `new` is worse than just a memory leak, it is undefined behavior. Pragmatically, apart from potential weird optimizations I am unaware of, it means that the destructor is not run; if such destructor was intended to have side-effect or release resources (other than memory), then it means trouble...

Answer (score 2):

If you break it down:

`new CClass()` -> dynamically-allocated instance pointer

`CClass clss` -> statically-allocated variable

`CClass clss = *new CClass();` -> copies the value pointed to by the temporary into clss

`&clss` -> the address of a statically-allocated variable

`delete &clss;` -> delete a statically-allocated variable (doesn't make sense)